# VS2017 MVC project wont open from .sln but Team Explorer works fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, sln-file

I'm working on a project which creates large XML files of 800k plus. I was having memory issues so I changed my IIS option in Tools>Options to 64 bit which helped. The problem worsened when my project hung and wasn't responding so I closed it forcibly. When I tried to re-open from the project .sln it told me it was incompatible even though the Team Explorer showed my latest changes as below.

[image]

It produced a Migration Report which looked like this
[image]

The project folder layout looks like this

[image]

I've tried running old backed up folders but VS2017 always says they are not recognised and tries to migrate them, some are only three or four days old! Has this reset broken my Visual Studio, do I need to re-install? I don't really have the time to mess around with this but if I can't restore from GIT/Team Explorer or backups, i don't know how to get my project running again. It seems ridiculous that Team Explorer shows my latest changes but Solution explorer is blank!

Comment: Have you ever been able to open this project?

Comment: Yes it has been running perfectly for over two months but after closing it down forcibly, yesterday, it now says it is incompatible which makes no sense. Not just the current version but previous backup versions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team explorer is only concerned with files on disk, it isn't trying to run anything. Solution explorer needs to open the solution file, read the contents, and interpret them in some way. It is failing to do this. This is why the former is working, when the latter isnt.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but how can a .sln file become incompatible the same day as it was opening perfectly unless there is something wrong with either a. Visual Studio or b. the .sln file?

Comment: Your source control system will be able to tell you if anything has changed with the solution file. If it hasn't, then the obvious culprit is Visual Studio. A quick google of your error message suggests that it might be related to your VS user profile being corrupted.